# Midlet throws javax.microedition.rms.RecordStoreException: error opening record store file in Samsung emulator

Tags: java-me, midlet, recordstore

I'm using the Samsung SDK 1.2.0 Beta in Netbeans 6.8.  I'm trying to test my midlet for accessing the record store management system.

This statement

```
 RecordStore rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore("Store", true);
```

runs fine when I'm using the Nokia SDK but it throws a RecordStoreException when I used it on Samsung.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already discovered what's wrong.  I installed Samsung SDK to a different folder with spaces instead of installing it to the default folder which is "C:\Samsung_SDK_120_Beta" or to another folder without using spaces.